# C++ iterate over iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I am currently "modernizing" my toy-compiler code to use as many C++11 features as possible to learn how to write modern C++. While looking at my code, searching for things to modernise I found this construct:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < _vector.size(); i++) {
   for (size_t j = 0; j < _vector[i].length(); j++) {
```

_vector is a `std::vector<std::string>` containing the source code of the file which needs to be compiled. Each `std::string` in the vector is a line of code which needs to be compiled. Before compilation takes place the compiler checks whether the code to be compiled has any syntax errors, and the first step of this check is to look out for missing semicolons. I do this by looking at each character one by one and checking if said character is a semicolon. If it is, I perform a check whether the semicolon is needed by building a kind of mini-syntax-tree and thereby determining if it is necessary. I currently access each character with `_vector[i][j]` which is very reminiscent of ANSI-C (this is how you access each character in an array of char*) and I want to replace this with iterators. As far as I know, an Iterator is a pointer-like construct which points to an element in a container/sequence/whatever. Applying the pointer analogy I deduced that an `std::vector<std::string>::iterator` points to a string in a vector, therefore a theoretical `std::vector<std::string>::iterator::iterator` would point to a single character in a string object. But because there isn't such thing in the STL the pointer analogy isn't of much use here. So my question is: How do I access each Character within a `std::vector<std::string>::iterator`?

Comment: You actually have 2 district iterator types, it's not possible to combine them in a single type.

Comment: I wouldn't go with iterators and stick the `[][]` approach, you might want to use `at()` instead for boundry check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [`iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) behaves like a pointer. So in your case, you can dereference the first iterator to get the [`string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and use a [`std::string::iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/begin) to access each character.

Another way is to use `operator->()` to directly get at the `std::string::iterator`, e.g.

```
for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator i = _vector.begin(); i != _vector.end(); ++i) {
    for (std::string::iterator j = i->begin(); j != i->end(); ++j) {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

With C++11, you can simplify this to

```
for (auto i = _vector.begin(); i != _vector.end(); ++i) {
    for (auto j = i->begin(); j != i->end(); ++j) {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

---

As @LightnessRacesinOrbit mentioned and @MateuszGrzejek already showed, the next step would be moving to a [Range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). A loop iterating from the first [`begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) to the last [`end()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end) element

```
for (auto i = _vector.begin(); i != _vector.end(); ++i) {
    // Do something with string (*i)
```

can be written as

```
for (auto &s : _vector) {
    // Do something with string (s)
```

or, if you don't modify string, make it `const`

```
for (const auto &s : _vector) {
    // Do something with string (s)
```

Comment: Using a range-for loop is an alternative of course. But I think, moving from an index based loop to a range-for loop, and understanding, requires an intermediate step: iterators. This is also evident from OP's question. Of course, there will always be people with a strong opinion about iterators vs range-for.

Comment: Just found it strange you recommended a C++11 "simpler" way without showing the C++11 simpler way :)

Comment: Ok, admitted I didn't look at it this way. I hope, the answer is more complete now and you like it even more. :-)

Answer (score 8):

If you have access to full C++ 11 support, why bother with explicit iterator types? That's where `auto` comes in:

```
std::vector<std::string> sv;
//fill vector...

for(const auto& s : sv)
{
    for(const auto& c : s)
    {
        //'c' represents current character
    }
}
```

We use [range-base for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) here. In first loop, `s` is a const reference <sup>**(*)**</sup> to current string from vector. Since [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) has support for iteration semantics, we can also iterate over it using `for`. `c` is a const reference to current character in string (`s`).

Live demo: **[click](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5093d7cdb65181cb)**.

---

<sup>**(*)**</sup> Since your loop seems to be read-only, const reference should be used. If you want to perform any modification, just change this from `const auto&` to `auto&`.